# After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 I cannot Access Gimp or Bitwarden

Tags: upgrade, system

When I click to open Gimp all I get is a black rectangle which if it was operating correctly would be the gimp startup window showing the gimp info. after a short time another window will open again totally black, this should be showing gimp tools and work area etc.
I have uninstalled gimp and BitWarden  and re-installed a few times but no change.
I have tried uninstalling Ubuntu 21.10 and re installing the whole system with no change. Any advice would be appreciated, in simple terms please as I am not a computer geek.
I have installed  gimp with flatpak now get the following error  message Gtk-Message: 19:04:13.370: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 19:04:13.387: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Can anyone tell me how I can get/install these missing modules?
Thanks.

Comment: have you considered using Bitwarden as a browser extension as outlined [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bitwarden-password-manager/) for Firefox?

Comment: Yes thanks  that worked for Bitwarden.